# Thunar: no templates in context menu

Tags: xfce, thunar

I already configured `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR` field in `~/.config/user-dirs.dir` ,

The folder is absolute path, and accessible, with several files inside.

But when I right click, the "Create Document" menu is still empty. Is there something I missed?

**UPDATE**

```
%> grep TEMP ~/.config/user-dirs.dir
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="/YY/XX/Templates/"
```

And that path exists and have files inside.

Comment: Does the entry in user.dirs.dir look like this: `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
`?

Comment: @Keith please check my updates

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash.

Comment: @Keith , no luck ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few tries , I found xdg-user-dirs-update command , and turns on the file name should be `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` instead.